# Couldn't find <Model> without an ID - rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models: RegisterHour and Employee

This is my model **RegisterHour**:

```
class RegisterHour < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :employee, class_name: 'Employee', foreign_key: 'employee_id'
end
```

And this my model: **Employee**

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :register_hours, dependent: :destroy
end
```

The mapping of my routes for this case

```
resources :employees do
   resources :register_hours
end
```

This my controller:

```
class RegisterHoursController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_employee
  before_action :set_hour, :set_employee_hour

  def index
   json_response(@employee.register_hours)
  end

  private
   def set_hour
     @register_hour = RegisterHour.find(params[:id])
   end

   def set_employee
     @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
   end

   def set_employee_hour
     @register_hour = @employee.register_hours.find_by(id: params[:id]) if @employee
   end


   def hour_params
    params.permit(:status)
   end
 end
```

So, when I run the route: http://my_url_in_local/employees/1/register_hours I got this error:

```
{
  "message": "Couldn't find RegisterHour without an ID"
}
```

I'm sooo confused because I have another controller with the same structure to manage admins and employees, and it works, but this controller don't.

I'm newbie with rails that's my confusion, if anyone can help me to understand what I'm doing wrong I gonna be super happy :)

Thank you!!

Comment: Try removing the `set_hour` before_action callback. It seems to me, if you have only an index action, you don't need a specific register hour id (according to your routes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking to how your routes are defined, you have something like this:

```
employee_register_hours GET    /employees/:employee_id/register_hours(.:format)     register_hours#index
                        POST   /employees/:employee_id/register_hours(.:format)     register_hours#create
 employee_register_hour GET    /employees/:employee_id/register_hours/:id(.:format) register_hours#show
                        PATCH  /employees/:employee_id/register_hours/:id(.:format) register_hours#update
                        PUT    /employees/:employee_id/register_hours/:id(.:format) register_hours#update
                        DELETE /employees/:employee_id/register_hours/:id(.:format) register_hours#destroy
              employees GET    /employees(.:format)                                 employees#index
                        POST   /employees(.:format)                                 employees#create
               employee GET    /employees/:id(.:format)                             employees#show
                        PATCH  /employees/:id(.:format)                             employees#update
                        PUT    /employees/:id(.:format)                             employees#update
                        DELETE /employees/:id(.:format)                             employees#destroy
```

If you see there, the URI routing the index action in RegisterHoursController only states that an `employee_id` in the params is expected. But in your private `set_hour` method, you're expecting that the params contain an `id` corresponding to an existing RecordHour record in your database:

```
RegisterHour.find(params[:id])
```

There's where your error is happening. As you're not sending that id, find is raising a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error.

You have a simple solution, that's to remove that method and everything related to it. So, your RegisterHoursController would end up in something much more simple:

```
class RegisterHoursController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
    json_response(@employee.register_hours)
  end

  private

  def hour_params
    params.permit(:status)
  end
end
```

Why? As you don't receive a RegisterHour id, then `set_hour` isn't necessary, this way `set_employee_hour` also becomes unnecessary, because `@employee.register_hours.find_by(id: params[:id])` is always going to return `nil`.

Removing that, you end up with set_employee, which can be just moved to the action where it belongs, allowing you to remove the `before_action` callback.

Notice, if you're using only the index action in RegisterHoursController, then you can avoid generating all other unneeded routes:

```
resources :employees do
  resources :register_hours, only: :index
end
```

Comment: So, I remove: set_employee, set_employee_hour and set_hour, and move the content of set_employee to my index, but I got an error: "ERROR:  column register_hours.employee_id does not exist\nLINE 1: ...CT \"register_hours\".* FROM \"register_hours\" WHERE \"register_...\n                                                             ^\nHINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column \"register_hours.employees_id\".\n>" And where I reference the: RegisterHour.find(params[:id]) for example if I want to use show method. Thanks!!

Comment: Are you able to get an employee record from the rails console and do `employee.regiser_hours`?

Comment: Maybe you need to update the `foreign_key` option you're using in the `belongs_to` method (RegisterHour model) to what's in your database; `employees_id`.

Comment: when I did my migration to set reference, I did this: `class AddEmployeesToRegisterHours < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :register_hours, :employees, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end`

Comment: I change my model like this: 
`class RegisterHour < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :employee, class_name: 'Employee', foreign_key: 'employees_id'
end`
`foreign_key: 'employee_id'` to `foreign_key: 'employees_id'` and in my controller the index method to:
`def index
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:employees_id])
    json_response(@employee.register_hours)
  end`
But the error says: `"message": "Couldn't find Employee without an ID"`
The field in my table: register_hours is employees_id (FK)

Comment: You also need to reference that column in the Employee model: `has_many :register_hours, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'employees_id'`

Comment: In the params you don't receive `employees_id` you receive `employee_id`.

Comment: Yes! you're right!! It works now!! Thank you so much!! :D

Comment: The main problem is in your migration. If you rollback and modify it to use `employee` instead of `employees`, you're not going to need to reference the foreign key in the relationships.

Comment: I will try modify my migration! Thank you! ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `before_action :set_hour, :set_employee_hour`.
As your index method doesn't contain `:id` params from routes.

You can Fix this by.

From:

`before_action :set_hour, :set_employee_hour`

To:

```
before_action :set_employee_hour
before_action :set_hour, except: [:index]
```

Comment: There's no `create` method in `RegisterHoursController`. If adding a callback that's never going to be executed, better to remove it, no?

Comment: The fact that you create a resources route it doesn't mean you automatically have a create action in the controller. Anyway, what I do see now is that the create method does not exist in the RegisterHoursController.